# Highcharts: visualize graph arcs to 3D scatter chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to visualize 3d graphs (all nodes & arcs are fixed) using https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable

In the given example, nodes work great (rotation, different colors, more info shown on hover...).

How can one add arcs in the existing demo? (having a list of arcs between nodes). Ideally, it would show the arc strength too, with a wider line when set to stronger.

Comment: You can connect points with series.lineWidth and series.lineColor options - if you need different line widths between some points, you need to group them into series - see the example http://jsfiddle.net/6caq2kca/

Comment: Thanks! If you post this an as answer, I'll mark accepted

Comment: Sure, I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect the points in a scatter3d series set [series.lineWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter3d.lineWidth) and series.lineColor.

```
series: [{
  name: 'Reading',
  colorByPoint: true,
  lineWidth: 1,
  lineColor: 'red',
  ...
}]
```

To connect points with different kind of color, it is needed to group them into series.

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/u3dxarz9/